# how to implement try catch blocks on linq queries that return dynamic types?

Tags: c#, linq, exception

first of all I want to know if its necessary to have linq statements that access the DAL in try catch blocks so you can input the errors into a log. secondly I have the following code, but as you can see it is returning a dynamic object  `new {s.ID,s.Name}`. I want to know how I should put such 
expressions in a try catch block.

should the whole block including the return statement be put inside the try catch block or should i create a custom object, and only put the initialization code that populates the custom object in the try catch block and if no exceptions are thrown return this custom object.

```
using (var rep = new Repository<Profile>())
            {
                var vals = rep.FindWhere(p => p.ProjectID == projectID)
                              .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                              .Select(
                                  s => new
                                      {
                                          s.ID,
                                          s.Name
                                      }).ToList();
                return Json(vals, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. What is the problem with the *anonymous* type?

Comment: hi, sorry, see the update please

Answer (score 2):

First question: No, unless you want to 'input the errors into a log'

Second question:

```
try
{
    using (var rep = new Repository<Profile>())
                {
                    var vals = rep.FindWhere(p => p.ProjectID == projectID)
                                  .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                                  .Select(
                                      s => new
                                          {
                                              s.ID,
                                              s.Name
                                          }).ToList();
                    return Json(vals, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // use ex here
   ErrorLog.Add(ex);

   // return whatever makes sense for you clientside
   return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

   // or just throw exception and use error callback in js
   throw;
}
```